# Is there a Regex expression to match all occurrences of a letter except in a certain string?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to find a Regex expression to match any occurrence of a letter in a string of lowercase [a-z] words, except when that letter is found in a certain word. The words are surrounded by whitespace, barring the first and last word as those are at the start and end of the string.

Specifically, I want to match any 'f' in the string except when found in the word 'def'. I have had very little experience with Regex in the past.

For example, given this string:

> 'def half def forbidden fluff def def tough off definite def'

the expression should select only the 'f's bolded as such:

> 'def hal**f** def **f**orbidden **f**lu**ff** def def tough o**ff** de**f**inite def'

Comment: Would the string that's the exception always be surrounded by whitespace? Or do you need to except `def:`, `def.` and `def,` as well? Would the string that's the exception always be made up of specific characters (like letters, or even just lowercase letters)?

Comment: For your information, you don't need "EDIT:", but it does no harm. It's not unusual to see that or something similar. I personally prefer just smooth and quiet edits. Same for edits of answers. Since a "whitespace" means a space, tab, newline or a few other character, words at the beginning or end of a string cannot be "surrounded by whitespace". As now worded, readers will know what you mean, it's just not quite correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try:

```
f(?<!\bdef\b)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`f`** - Matching `f` literally.
>
> **`(?<!\bdef\b)`** - Represents a [**negative look-behind**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) not matching any occurrence of the word `def`. If you want `def` to be case-insensitive then please use the flag `\i`.
>
> **`\b`** - Represents a [**word boundary**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for matching the exact word (in this case `def`) or characters inside.

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/wpmqA6/3)

Answer (score 0):

Use a PCRE pattern like

```
(?<!\S)def(?!\S)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|f
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/dG7xYu/1). It matches `def` inside whitespace boundaries, and skips the match, and matches `f` in all other places.

[image]

If you'd like to make it case insensitive, add `(?i)`:

```
(?i)(?<!\S)def(?!\S)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|f
```